# Why are my footer logos including the margin-left?

Tags: html, css

I have run into a problem regarding the logos in my footer. There are four logos in my footer (a Pinterest logo, a Facebook logo, a Twitter logo and a Google+ logo). Each of the four logos are linked to seperate webpages however, I can't understand why the white space (margin-left: 15px) between the logos can also be clicked on. If anyone could explain why this occurs and how I could go about fixing this issue (ONLY the logo should be clicked on to access the link, not the white space in between), it would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Here is the relevant HTML code:

```
<body> 
     <div id="footer"> 
         <div id="footerlogos"> 
             <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/fwtemplates/" target="_blank">
                 <img src="http://s8.postimg.org/9rkvn5myp/pinteresticon.png" alt="pinterest icon" height="22px"/>
             </a>
             <a href="https://www.facebook.com/freewebsitetemplates" target="_blank">
                 <img src="http://s1.postimg.org/xbrb5tse3/facebookicon.png" alt="facebook icon" height="22px"/>
             </a>
             <a href="https://twitter.com/fwtemplates" target="_blank">
                 <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/z4hzkw8xh/twittericon.png" alt="twitter icon" height="22px"/>
             </a>
             <a href="https://plus.google.com/118363260425872001433" target="_blank">
                 <img src="http://s2.postimg.org/63vc1sv8l/google_icon.png" alt="google+ icon" height="22px"/>
             </a>
         </div> 
     </div> 
</body>
```

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
#footer {
     width: 100%; 
     height: 50px; 
     background-color: #999999;
     border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
     padding-right: 20px; 
     padding-left: 20px; 
     clear: both; 
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}

#footerlogos {
     height: 100%; 
     line-height: 45px; 
     display: inline-block; 
     float: right; 
}

#footerlogos img {
     opacity: 0.6; 
     vertical-align: middle; 
     margin-left: 15px; 
}

#footerlogos a:link {
     text-decoration: none; 
}
```

Here is a link to the JSFiddle with only the relevant HTML and CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/kqwm5m45/

Comment: it isn't for me on your JSFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your clickable element is the `img` which has a `margin-left: 15px`. Everything contained in the `a`-tag is clickable. This is the expected behaviour.

In your case, you won't this. So you should move your `margin-left: 15px` away from `#footerlogos img` but to `#footerlogos a`.

```
#footerlogos a {
     margin-left: 15px; 
}

#footerlogos img {
     opacity: 0.6; 
     vertical-align: middle; 
}
```